# ASP.NET Core + Angular static route

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I`ve created default ASP.NET Core + Angular project. I need to open angular app only by link /angular. Also when angular routing have to be under /angular link too, like "/angular/profile" - profile page, "/angular/item/22" - page with item.
By links which don`t contains "/angular" I need open static files or MVC views.

Default project use SPA, so I dont want to change it.

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: I found how to start angular app by link: `spa.Options.DefaultPage = "/angular";`, but after using in app routing link resets with "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify the base URL to view from the Angular ClientApp folder, try to set `href` attribute of `base`  by going to **ClientApp** > **src** > **index.html** like below :

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>ClientApp</title>
 <base href="/angular">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
```

After that, the URL like this:

[image]

There is no need to change the UseSpa method, my UseSpa() method as below:

```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501 
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```